# java.util.NoSuchElementException: Read words from a file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

what`s wrong with this simple java program?

I am trying to read words from a file and get the following exception:

```
complication
dilemma
lavender
issue
happy
weird
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1416)
    at com.recrawl.util.ReadWordsTextfile.readWordsFromTextFile(ReadWordsTextfile.java:32)
    at com.recrawl.util.ReadWordsTextfile.main(ReadWordsTextfile.java:13)
```

As you can see I get the words however, I also get an exception. I am using the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String path = "Word_and_phrases";
    ReadWordsTextfile r = new ReadWordsTextfile();
    r.readWordsFromTextFile(path);  
}

public ArrayList<String> readWordsFromTextFile(String path) {
    ArrayList<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();

    FileInputStream fileIn = null;
    try {
        fileIn = new FileInputStream(path);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(fileIn);
    while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
        String word = scan.next();
        word = word.replace(",", "");
        System.out.println(word);
        resultList.add(word);
    }
    scan.close();
    System.out.println(resultList.toString());
    return resultList;
}
```

I really appreciate your answers!

**UPDATE**

The content of the txt file looks like that:

```
complication, dilemma, lavender, issue, happy, weird
```

Line 32 ist that:

```
    String word = scan.next();
```

Comment: Which line is line 32? And what is the file you're reading? Can you post the relevant part

Comment: @HamzahMalik Pls have a look at my update.

Comment: NoSuchElementException occurs when there aren't any more characters to read AFAIK. So it crashes when it gets to the last word

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use :

```
while(scan.hasNext())
```

Instead of:

```
while(scan.hasNextLine())
```

`hasNext` is implemented to work with `next()` while `hasNextLine` is implemented to work with `nextLine()`